# Limit of the difference of two sequences

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, algorithms

I have three sequences generated by an algorithm: $\{x^k\}_k$, $\{y^k\}_k$, and $\{z^k\}_k$ such that $z^k = x^k - y^k$ where $k$ denotes the number of iterations. While making derivations, I ended up proving that
$$ \underset{k \rightarrow \infty}{\lim} (x^{k+1}-y^k) = 0$$

Now, I'm a bit confused if I'm allowed to say that $\underset{k \rightarrow \infty}{\lim} z^k = 0$ or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x^{k}=k$  and $y^{k}=k+1$ then $x^{k+1}-y^{k} \to 0$ but $x^{k}-y^{k} \to -1$